# Call Stored Procedures from Entity Framework return value from temp tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4.5 and EF. I imported some stored procedures into my ADO.NET Entity Data Model. I have my `.edmx` and `XX.tt` with my `StoreProcedure_Result.cs`.

But there is a stored procedure that do not have a `_result.cs` file

This is because the stored procedure returns

```
 select from #TempTable
```

When I want to import that function to create a complex type, it sees that the function do not return any value..

I thinks that return value from temp tables it is not allowed.

Any ideas how can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Is that temp table being created *inside* the stored procedure? Or does it exist before the stored procedures is run? Also: what if you use `select (list of columns) from #TempTable` (instead of `select * ...` which is what I assume you're doing) - does that change anything when trying to import that stored procedure and creating a complex type for its result set?

Comment: I use select val1, val2 from #temptable... and i créate it inside de SP... I solve it putting "SET FMTONLY OFF; " inside the SP.. Anyway, other solution may be posible.. Thanks..

Answer (score -1):

Based on my personal experience, If you use #temp or ##temp table in stored procedure and calling that procedure from MVC Entity framework (.edmx) then it will not work & it will return -1 always.

There can be 2 solutions:

1. Modify the stored procedure, replace the #temp or ##temp table with some other concrete logic. And then update .edmx then try again to call the procedure.
2. Or the simple one solution would be call that particular stored procedure using traditional ADO.NET (using the SQLConnection/SQLCommand objects ) and get the returning table value in DataSet or DataTable.

Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).